# How to call a function after change()

Tags: jquery

The reason why I need to achieve what I'm asking here are a little convoluted because I'm working off of a CMS that already has some jQuery stuff going on. But basically, I need to call 2 functions when user either clicks on links or select from a drop down (they both do the same thing), let's call them `foo()` and `bar()`.

I can get it to work when user clicks:

```
$('.links').on("click", "a", function() {
    $(".dropdown select").change();
    bar();
    return false;
});

$(".dropdown select").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        foo();
    });
});
```

The problem is that bar() needs to be called after the `change()` event. I can't call `bar()` inside the change() event. When user clicks, no problem. But I can't figure out how to call `bar()` directly from `change()` but when everything in `change()` is done.

Is there a way to add some kind of callback on `change()`? I tried a few different syntaxes, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Just put it at the end of the change function handler, right? Do you mean there are multiple change event handlers and you want to call `foo()` after all of them execute?

Comment: concept is a bit vague, not clear what the sequencing problems are, or why `bar()` can't be called within change handler

Comment: Maybe triggering click event on $(".links").trigger('click') would help, but that will trigger click event on all elements with class links

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.links').on('click', 'a', function(){
   myFunc(); 
   return false;
});
$('.dropdown select').on('change', myFunc);

function myFunc(){
  $('select option:selected').each(function(){
    foo();
  });
  bar();
}
```

Why not add a third function to handle this behaviour? (and technically keep the same amount of function calls since we can remove the anonymous function handled by a `select` `change`!)